# Popup form using asp.net and javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hi I am new for web development. I have an application which consists of a button. On clicking the button a popup window should appear which consists of 2 fields and a button. On clicking button in Popup window 2 fields in popup has to be saved in to database. How to implement this using **ASP.NET and javascript** ?

Answer (score 1):

Try even this one...

http://www.scriptiny.com/2009/05/javascript-popup-box/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this...

[JQueryUI Pop Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

First you need to add jquery library in your page then on the next line add the library for the jqueryui

It's very easy...